# SSRS connection errors

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, connection-pooling

I'm getting the error below occasionally in SQL Server 2008 R2 Reporting Services.  I have around 25 subscriptions that run close to midnight every night and a couple times they've all failed with this error.  I'm not sure if it's a red herring but I killed most of the connections (90% of the connections to this server are from SSRS, and most of those are to ReportServer db) last night around 10:00 and no errors occurred for several hours.  This is a relatively new installation but I didn't tweak anything when I migrated from the old server so I don't know why this is happening.  I might be able to work around it by increasing the max pool size and killing unused connections but I'd rather not do that.

> ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.DataSourceOpenException: , Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.DataSourceOpenException: Cannot create a connection to data source 'MyDB'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

It seems like the problem is that connections are not being reused, but only by SSRS, not by other apps hitting the server.  Why would that be?

Comment: Are these data-driven subscriptions or regular?

Comment: I have some data-driven subs that run throughout the day but only 1 or 2 of the 25 that run around midnight are data driven.  You might be onto something though.  Is there a way to easily correlate the connections with their source report?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things to consider especially since you have data-driven subscriptions.

1. Try to stagger the time they are scheduled to run at so that they aren't all competing for resources at the same time.
2. Adjust the timeout on the query for the data-driven subscriptions (this is probably your main issue). The report and the subscription each have their own separate timeouts set.

Comment: The data-driven subscriptions query timeouts range from 30 to 200 seconds, but most (if not all; I'm checking that) use shared data sources.  Why would the query timeout matter in this case if none of them is set to 0 (unlimited)?

Comment: Your error message specifically mentions timeouts. If one of the subscription queries times out, you will get this type of error message for your subscription status. It's best to give them each at least a few minutes.

Comment: The queries aren't timing out, I would see that in my SQL Sentry monitor.  The problem is that the connections aren't being made to begin with.  I forgot we were talking about query timeouts and not connection timeouts, in my previous comment.